# Cannot get routing to work with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, web

I'm creating a web portfolio and the main page has a menu. When the user clicks 'video' I want the site to go to mywebsite.com/video and go to video.html. I'm using AngularJS and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

index.html

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#events">Upcoming Events</a>
    <a href="#cv">CV</a>
    <a href="#video">Video Reel</a>
</nav>
<div class="ng-view"></div>
</body>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when(
    '/', {
        redirectTo: '/home'
    })
    .when('/portfolio', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/portfolio.html'
    })
    .when('/events', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/events.html'
    })
    .when('/cv', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/cv.html'
    })
    .when('/video', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/video.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try to add `$locationProvider` service into config and change `href` attributes

```
//html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#/events">Upcoming Events</a>
    <a href="#/cv">CV</a>
    <a href="#/video">Video Reel</a>
</nav>
<div class="ng-view"></div>
</body>

//js
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when(
    '/', {
        redirectTo: '/'
    })
    .when('/portfolio', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/portfolio.html'
    })
    .when('/events', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/events.html'
    })
    .when('/cv', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/cv.html'
    })
    .when('/video', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/video.html'
    })
    // removed other routes ... *snip
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    }
);

// enable html5Mode for pushstate ('#'-less URLs)
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
//$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Comment: don't get the error, but clicking 'Video Reel' also doesn't work, the url changes, but the page stays the same

Comment: do you have video.html?

Comment: my urls are messed up as well, when I click on "Video Reel" i get http://localhost:8000/#!/#video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146558/discussion-between-hasan-and-kat).

Answer (score 1):

It should be,

```
 <a href="#/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
 <a href="#/events">Upcoming Events</a>
 <a href="#/cv">CV</a>
 <a href="#/video">Video Reel</a>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/9JLnhrLsynN7Ua92vW73?p=preview)**

Comment: @PankajParkar where?

Comment: I tried that and it still isn't working. I'm also getting: angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: @Kat Then check your dependencies are properly injected, check the demo

Comment: commented out $locationProvider as that was causing the errors, but clicking the 'video' link still does nothing

Comment: @Kat did you check the attached demo

Comment: no error, it just isn't working. I click 'Video Reel' and nothing happens. I updated the question to show what code i'm using now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146553/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-kat).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should inject $locationProvider because you are using it but I do not see the injection.

Comment: thank you, i commented out $locationProvider for now